# Display drop down values upto the width of drop down box using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image]

If option value is large, then I need to cut the display value with "...."
for e.g For attached image, option value should display as '11111....' if value is going beyond width of drop down box

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       values: [12312312321, 1231232142412, 1231232313, 12312312312],
     }
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <form>
         <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
           <ControlLabel>Select</ControlLabel>
           <br />
           <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">
             <option value="select">Select...</option>
              {this.state.values.map(num => {
                 return <option key={num} value={num}>{num.toString().length > 6 ? num.toString().slice(0, 5).concat('...') : num}</option>             
              })}
           </FormControl>
         </FormGroup>
       </form>
     )
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vkdchtq8/).

Comment: I just noticed you asked for a css version. I tried a few options however I was unable to come up with a workable solution. Applying textOverflow: ellipsis and maxWidth:'100px' doesn't seem to work for an option tag.